# The convergence of $ \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ln(\frac{n+1}{n-1})$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Good morning, I have tried to prove the convergence with the application of the criterion of comparison.

I have used this increase:

$$ \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)  < \sum_{n=2}^{+\infty} \frac{4}{(\ln 3)^n}$$

therefore, the sum converges, because is lower than a geometric sum

Is this increase correct?

Can I improve it?

Thanks

Comment: If your method relies on the inequality $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}} \ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)  < \frac{4}{(\ln 3)^n},$$ this is unfortunate since the inequality is wrong.

Comment: $\ln(n+1) - \ln(n-1) = \frac{2}{c_n}$ for $c_n \in (n-1,n+1)$, so your series behaves close to $\sim \sum\limits_{n=2}^{\infty} \frac{2}{n^{3/2}}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have

$$\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac{2}{n-1}\right)\sim_\infty\frac{2}{n}$$
hence

$$\frac1{\sqrt n}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)\sim_\infty\frac2{n^{3/2}}$$
so by comparison with a Riemann convergent series the given series is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid asymptotic estimates by noting that $\ln(1+x)\le x$ for $x\ge 1$, so that

$$\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)=\ln\left(1+\frac2{n-1}\right)\le\frac2{n-1}$$

for $n\ge 2$. Thus,

$$\sum_{n\ge 2}\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\ln\left(\frac{n+1}{n-1}\right)\le\sum_{n\ge 2}\ \frac2{(n-1)\sqrt{n}}=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac2{n\sqrt{n+1}}\le2\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac1{n^{3/2}}\;.$$